# Force content type image/* only download.file R

Tags: r, image, content-type

I'm downloading some images from links in googlesheet, the problem is that some of those links, redirect to other link eg. google drive or transfer big files, and despite this, R tries to download something and end up with a Content type 'text/html; ...' instead of telling me it found an error or nothing to download, I need a way to tell R, if you can recognize Content type 'image/*' then download, otherwise pop an error or tell me. That´s beacuse at the end of the exercise, I need to know which links gave me empty files, to correct them.

Here's some code with  Content type 'image/*' and what I need to download

```
e = 'https://kanu.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/155806/Alimento-Agility-Gold-Grandes-Adultos-para-perro-1_1.jpg'
f = 'https://barranquilla.gruposotillo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rosa-veuve.png'
download.file(url = e,'name.jpg',mode = 'wb')
download.file(url = f,'name.jpg',mode = 'wb')
```

Expected behaviour
[image]

And some code with links which I need to recognize as 'bad' and not procced with the downloading

```
a = 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupermercadocomunal.com%2Flicores%2F4369-tequila-jose-cuervo-reposado-375-ml-7501035010284.html&psig=AOvVaw2CyVcs9npcsOt9IZuG2s1g&ust=1592092231256000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMjO6fG7_ekCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ'
c = 'http://tbf.me/a/BbF0Ud'
d = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-puT-0__ZXkEcKJpZQQPZuu4rrdNSwCC?usp=sharing'
download.file(url = a,'name.jpg',mode = 'wb')
download.file(url = c,'name.jpg',mode = 'wb')
download.file(url = d,'name.jpg',mode = 'wb')
```

Links I need to recognize as error:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the content of a link in R using httr library. Say this is your link:

```
a <- "http://norwegianarts.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/NBM-Immortal-copyright-Nuclear-Blast-e1443452460395-1440x640.jpg"
```

Then, by using httr's get() function you'll get the link content:

```
example <- GET(a)
```

And this will return a json, rendered as a list in R, the you just move to the part where you wish to be, which in this case must be $content.

Comment: Very strange that this was the accepted anser. It doesn't appear to be doing any of the selections of jpg content that was the crux of the question.